# Microsoft Analysis Server parallel processing partitions

Tags: sql-server, ssis, server, analysis

I have a Microsoft Analysis Server with version 13.0.4411.0 - 2016SP1 with CU1. Also, I have a SSIS package developed in Visual Studio 2015 with some Analysis Services Processing Tasks put in parallel processing. A while ago, I had Analysis Server version 2008. With this last version my ssis was working fine but when I changed to 2016SP1 nothing is working: the service of server is stopped after a couple of minutes. I would mention that I have an Enterprise edition. Any ideas?

Comment: I will suggest you build the package(s) from scratch. Not sure how much work that would require though.

Comment: I've built the package from scratch in VS 2015 and I've changed a property for each task - MaximumErrorCout, from 1 to 100000. Also, I've changed the job which rules the package by CmdExec from "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn..." to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn...". Now. it seems it works.

Comment: Great. Please remember to give me a vote.